# Compute $M=\sum_{n=1}^{40}[\frac{n^2}{2}]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Compute $$M=\sum_{n=1}^{40}[\frac{n^2}{2}]$$
>   here the square bracket stands for greatest integer function.

**My attempt**

The first few terms in $M$ are $$M=0+(2+4)+(8+12)+(18+24)+(...)$$

I have grouped them to show that I've identified that the difference between $(a,b)=b-a$ is successively increasing as $2,4,6,...$. However that still does not help me solve the problem in any way! I understand AP, GP, HP, AGP, yet none of it comes to rescue here :(

How to solve this problem? Few hints would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even $n$:
$$\left[ \frac{n^2}{2}\right] = \frac{n^2}{2}$$
Odd $n$:
$$\left[ (2n-1)^2/2 \right] = \left[ 2n^2 - 2n + 1/2 \right] = 2n(n-1)$$
So if $x$ is even, then its term is $x^2/2$. If $x$ is odd, then its term is $(x-1)(x+1)/2$.

---

The summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{40} \left[ \frac{n^2} 2 \right] = \sum_{n=1}^{20}\left(\left[ \frac{(2n)^2} 2\right] + \left[ \frac{(2n-1)^2} 2 \right] \right)$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^{20}\left(2n^2 + 2n(n-1)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{20}\left(4n^2 - 2n\right)$$
$$= 4\sum_{n=1}^{20}n^2 - 2 \sum_{n=1}^{20}n$$
...which I will let you solve.

Answer (score 1):

We can write [k]=k- $<k>$ where k is any positive real number box indicates integer function and arrow brackets indicate non integer part hence our sum S $=\sum_1^{40}( \frac {n^2}{2}-<n^2/2>) $. Now I hope you know how to calculate $n^2$ for integer n and notice that the non integer part would be $0$ for even integers and $\frac {1}{2} $ for odd integers. I hope you can continue from here.